# Tool for multiple pattern search and replace

Tags: text, search-and-replace

I am looking for an easy to use tool that will allow me to have batch of search/replace pairs.  Rolling out to different environments requires us to search/replace server names in database scripts.  I would like to create a list of search/replace pairs that I can run a file through to prepare it for an environment.

Any OS would be interesting, but my specific need is for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

For *nix, generally some sort of tool that support regular expressions would be used.  Someone would probably use sed, awk, Perl, or Python.  You might consider [wingrep](http://www.wingrep.com/) for windows.

Answer (score 0):

FART.. Find And Replace Tool.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/fart-it/

It can be command line scripted if you need.

Comment: if fart-it does multiple replacements, prove it

Answer (score 0):

PowerGREP will do what you need.  They include a 15-day trial, but it is for 15 days that you are actually using the product, so its quite a nice trial.

Once you start up the program there are two drop downs beside each other; 'Action Type' and 'Search Type'.  Change Action Type to 'Search and replace'.  Change 'Search Type' to 'List of Literal Text' or 'List of regular expressions'.  You can add and remove Search/replacement Pairs.

http://www.powergrep.com/index.html
[image]
<sub>(source: [biffis.com](http://www.biffis.com/crap/powergrep.png))</sub>